Finding the range of $x$ for which $\left\lfloor x^2\right\rfloor+6\left\lfloor x+\sqrt{3}\right\rfloor+4=18$

Find the range of $x$ for which the following condition holds
$$f(x):=\left\lfloor x^2\right\rfloor+6\left\lfloor x+\sqrt{3}\right\rfloor+4=18.$$

My thoughts :

$f(0)=10$
$f(2-\sqrt3)=16$
$f(1)=17$
$f(3-\sqrt3)=23$

So, as far as I have guessed, the value of $x$ will be between $1$ and $3-\sqrt{3}$.
But I really don't know that for what values of $x$ the condition holds.

You don't need all those parentheses. $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ and $\lfloor x+\sqrt3\rfloor$ is fine, for example, and easier to read, unless you mean something in particular by them?

No, I used parenthesis for denoting the range of $x$.

How does writing $\lfloor (x^2)\rfloor$ "denote the range of $x?$"

Just get some paper and draw a picture. You know that the value changes across points where $x^2$ is an integer  and points where $x + \sqrt 3$ is an integer. Draw some axes with $x$ axis marked at the integers, then $\pm \sqrt n$  for $n$ up to, say $20,$  then the $n - \sqrt 3$  for $n$ from $-10$ to $10.$  and calculate the value of $y$  from the formula with the floor symbols, and plot those points. That's it. Plot some points. You will learn, and retain, more than you are learning now. Oh, the $y$ value will jump at those special points, but be constant in between each pair.

Meanwhile: nothing wrong with using a calculator  here. Plus it is a little better  to plot using $x$  values chosen in between  those special points, then drw a horizontal segment through that $x,y$  point, reaching the special $x$ value on either side.  That way, accuracy of the calculator is hardly important.

What happens if $~x = 1 + 1/6~?$  What happens if $~0 \leq x < 1 ~?$  What happens if $~x < 0 ~?$

Some thoughts.  $[M + 4] =[M] + 4$ so we can reduce.  As $1 < \sqrt 3 < 2$ we have $[x +\sqrt 3] = [x]+1$ or $x+2$.  Depending on whether the fractional part of $x$ is less then or equal or greater than the fractional part of $\sqrt 3$.

$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}$
Let $b:=\floor{x+\sqrt3}$, i.e.
$$b\in\Bbb Z,\quad b-\sqrt3\le x<b-\sqrt3+1.$$
Your problem is equivalent to $\floor{x^2}=14-6b$, i.e.
$$14-6b\le x^2<15-6b.$$
This implies $0<15-6b$, i.e. (since $b\in\Bbb Z$) $b\le2$.
If $b=2$ then $0<2-\sqrt3\le x<3-\sqrt3\approx1.3$ and $x\ge\sqrt{14-6b}=\sqrt2\approx1.4$, contradiction.
If $b=1$ then $x^2\le\max((1-\sqrt3)^2,(2-\sqrt3)^2)\approx0.5$ and $x^2\ge14-6b=8$, contradiction again.
Therefore, $b\le0$, so that $x<b-\sqrt3+1<0$, and we are left to solve
$$\begin{cases}b\in\Bbb Z_{\le0}\\
b-\sqrt3\le x<b-\sqrt3+1\\
-\sqrt{15-6b}<x\le-\sqrt{14-6b}.
\end{cases}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
A necessary condition is
$$\begin{cases}b\in\Bbb Z_{\le0}\\
b-\sqrt3\le-\sqrt{14-6b}\\
-\sqrt{15-6b}<b-\sqrt3+1
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}b\in\Bbb Z_{\le0}\\
b^2+2(3-\sqrt3)b-11\ge0\\
b^2+2b(4-\sqrt3)-11-2\sqrt3<0
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}b\in\Bbb Z\\
b\le-3+\sqrt3-\sqrt{(3-\sqrt3)^2+11}\approx-4.8\\
b>-4+\sqrt3-\sqrt{(4-\sqrt3)^2+11+2\sqrt3}\approx-6.7.
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$b=-6\quad\text{or}\quad b=-5.$$
For each of these two values of $b$, we even have
$$\begin{cases}
b\le-3+\sqrt3-\sqrt{(3-\sqrt3)^2+12}\approx-4.97\\
b>-4+\sqrt3-\sqrt{(4-\sqrt3)^2+10+2\sqrt3}\approx-6.58
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
b-\sqrt3\le
-\sqrt{15-6b}\\
-\sqrt{14-6b}\le b-\sqrt3+1,
\end{cases}$$
so that the system in \eqref{eq1A} reduces to its second line: $-\sqrt{15-6b}<x\le-\sqrt{14-6b}$.
The set of solutions is therefore
$$(-\sqrt{51},-\sqrt{50}]\cup(-\sqrt{45},-\sqrt{44}],$$
which is confirmed by these two WA plots:



I come from read your answer. It is EXACT!. I put an upvote.

Thank you very very very much @Anne Bauval
